# Not getting values and passing to controller from multiselect-Kendo MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, multi-select

I am working o getting values and passing them to controller to use SQL query for filtering. The problem is that while I can pass values from all other components such that textbox to controller, I couldnt do it for multiselect. Whatever I do, I am getting error message like "null" values or

> "uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'value' of null "

or

> "uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'val' of null "

Here is my controller and view;

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model.GridModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
            columns.Bound(p => p.RaporNo);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BankaRaporNo);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Eksper);
            columns.Bound(p => p.TalepTarihi).Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.BeklenenTeslimTarihi).Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.RaporOnayTarihi).Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.UzmanAdi);
            columns.Bound(p => p.DenetmenAdi);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SorumluUzman);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Onayci);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Banka);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SubeAdi);
            columns.Bound(p => p.MusteriUnvani);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Ili);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Ilcesi);
            columns.Bound(p => p.FiiliKullanimDurumu);
            columns.Bound(p => p.AnaTasinmazVasfi);
            columns.Bound(p => p.MevcutAlan);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Firma).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.SurecAciklama).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Ay).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Yil).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Mahalle).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Koy).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Pafta).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.EskiAda).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.EskiParsel).Hidden();

            columns.Bound(p => p.StartBeklenenTeslimTarihi).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.StartRaporOnayTarihi).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.StartTalepTarihi).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndBeklenenTeslimTarihi).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndRaporOnayTarihi).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndTalepTarihi).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.SurecAciklama).Hidden();

        })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
            .Scrollable()
            .Sortable()
            .AutoBind(true)
            .Selectable()
            .Navigatable()
            .Filterable()
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
                .Excel(excel => excel
                .FileName("Excel_Dokumu.xlsx")
                .Filterable(true)
                .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Function"))
             )
             .Excel(excel => excel.AllPages(true))
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                .Sort(sort => sort.Add("Id").Ascending())
                .Create(update => update.Action("Function_Create", "Function"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Function_Read", "Function").Data("additionalInfo"))
                .PageSize(10)

            )

    )


<script>
                        function additionalInfo(e) {
                            return {
                                Id: $("#id").val(),
                                RaporNo: $("#rapor_no").val(),
                                BankaRaporNo: $("#banka_rapor_no").val(),
                                Eksper: $("#eksper").val(),

                                StartTalepTarihi: $("#startTalep").val(),
                                EndTalepTarihi: $("#endTalep").val(),
                                StartBeklenenTeslimTarihi: $("#startBeklenenTeslim").val(),
                                EndBeklenenTeslimTarihi: $("#endBeklenenTeslim").val(),
                                StartRaporOnayTarihi: $("#startRaporOnay").val(),
                                EndRaporOnayTarihi: $("#endRaporOnay").val(),

                                UzmanAdi: $("#uzman").val(),
                                DenetmenAdi: $("#denetmen").val(),
                                SorumluUzman: $("#sorumlu_uzman").val(),
                                Onayci: $("#onay").val(),
                                Banka: $("#banka").val(),
                                SubeAdi: $("#sube").val(),
                                MusteriUnvani: $("#musteri_unvani").val(),
                                Firma: $("#firma").val(),
                                Ili: $("#iller").val(),
                                Ilcesi: $("#ilce").val(),
                                FiiliKullanimDurumu: $("#fiili_kullanim").val(),
                                SurecAciklama: $("#multiSelectDurumu").data('kendoMultiSelect').val(),
                                Ay: $("#multiselectAy").val(),
                                Yil: $("#multiselectYıl").val(),
                                Mahalle: $("#mahalle").val(),
                                Koy: $("#koy").val(),
                                Pafta: $("#pafta").val(),
                                EskiAda: $("#ada").val(),
                                EskiParsel: $("#parsel").val(),
                            };
                        }
                </script>
```

And controller;

```
public ActionResult Function_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string CustId, string Id, string RaporNo,
        string BankaRaporNo, string Eksper, DateTime? StartTalepTarihi, DateTime? EndTalepTarihi, DateTime? StartBeklenenTeslimTarihi, 
        DateTime? EndBeklenenTeslimTarihi, DateTime? StartRaporOnayTarihi, DateTime? EndRaporOnayTarihi, string UzmanAdi, string DenetmenAdi, 
        string SorumluUzman, string Onayci, string Banka, string SubeAdi, string MusteriUnvani, string Ili, string Ilcesi, string FiiliKullanimDurumu, 
        string SurecAciklama, string Ay, string Yil, string Mahalle, string Koy, string Pafta, string EskiAda, string EskiParsel, string Firma)
    {
        string CustIdCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("CustId").Value.ToString();
        Model.GridModel datas = new Model.GridModel();
        List<Model.GridModel> dataModel = datas.GetAll(CustIdCookie, Id, RaporNo, BankaRaporNo, Eksper, StartTalepTarihi, EndTalepTarihi, StartBeklenenTeslimTarihi
            , EndBeklenenTeslimTarihi, StartRaporOnayTarihi, EndRaporOnayTarihi,
            UzmanAdi, DenetmenAdi, SorumluUzman, Onayci, Banka, SubeAdi, MusteriUnvani, Ili, Ilcesi, FiiliKullanimDurumu, SurecAciklama, Ay, Yil, Mahalle, Koy, Pafta, EskiAda, EskiParsel, Firma);
        return Json(dataModel.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: That error is a javascript error. Check all the selectors in `additionalInfo` and see which one is not really selecting anything.

Comment: There is no error in additionalInfo  method, because when I unselect SurecAciklama , returning nor error and binding data to grid.

Comment: Well that is what the error is saying: *uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'val' of null*

Comment: solved with kendo updating.